# Passing secureObject array as VSTS variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template that deploys Key Vault and populates it with secrets. It does creates secrets, based on how many arrays are in the parameter secretsObject. For example if I have:

```
"secretsObject": {
  "type": "secureObject",
  "defaultValue": {
    "secrets": [
      {
        "secretName": "exampleSecret1",
        "secretValue": "secretVaule1"
      },
      {
        "secretName": "exampleSecret2",
        "secretValue": "secretValue2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The template will create 2 Secrets. So this is the line that I put into .parameters.json to deploy the template from Visual Studio:

```
        "secrets": [
      {
        "secretName": "exampleSecret1",
        "secretValue": "secretVaule1"
      },
      {
        "secretName": "exampleSecret2",
        "secretValue": "secretValue2"
      }
    ]
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to past such line into VSTS as a variable (to overwrite parameter). [This is the ARM template I'm using](https://pastebin.com/XmwffVi3)

```
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidDeploymentParameterKey.
One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.
task result: Failed
Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may check the source code of how it parses the parameters https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeployment

Comment: The value is the object, so try to specify the value to `{"secrets":[{......}]}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referencing. I've just referenced `{"secrets":[{"secretName":"exampleSecret1","secretValue":"secretVaule1"},{"secretName":"exampleSecret2","secretValue":"secretValue2"},{"secretName":"exampleSecret3","secretValue":"secretVaule3"}]}` and received an error: `Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'secretsObject' at line '1' and column '1411' is not valid.'.
Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.`

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you please tell me if you resolve this issue.

Comment: No, didn’t solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the issue in Azure Resource Group deployment task and I submit a feedback here: VSTS build/release task: [Override template parameters of Azure Resource Group Deployment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/173606/vsts-buildrelease-task-override-template-parameter.html).

The workaround is that you can update the parameter file during the build/release (e.g. parameter.json) and specify this parameter file in Azure Resource Group deployment task.

There are many ways to update file, such as [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Update:

Feedback in Gitgub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6108

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it doesn't work. You should report that issue on GitHub.

Comment: I report it on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6108